# Using the ORDER BY clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use a keyword that would order the results in my SELECT QUERY by the number of times they appear in the data table?

MySQL:

```
  SELECT * FROM interests ORDER BY (keyword)
```

The table values:

```
hiking
running
swimming
hiking
photography
swimming
hiking
```

If the Order in which they are returned is based on the frequency of each values occurence in the table it would be:

```
hiking
hiking
hiking
swimming
swimming
running
photography
```

If there is no one particular keyword, how can I achieve this with SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Try group by and count(*).  Don't know your table schema, so if you show that it would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(keyword) AS cnt, keyword
FROM interested
GROUP BY keyword
ORDER BY cnt
```

would give you the count of each keyword in ascending order. But you wouldn't get 3 hiking entries, 2swimming, etc... just `hiking,3`, `swimming,2`, etc...

Comment: Use `order by cnt desc` to get the highest count first.

Comment: What if I wanted to use SELECT *?

Comment: you can select as many fields as you want. the results might be somewhat undefined if you're pulling out fields that aren't grouped/aggregated.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    interests a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  keyword, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROm    interests
            GROUP BY keyword
        ) b ON a.keyword = b.keyword
ORDER   BY b.totalCount DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f937/4)

Comment: This is awesome thank you! Now, how could I get my SQL to only display one of each value? And how can I get the count for each value?

Comment: what do you mean number for each value? isn't it the answer of @MarcB ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    t1.*,count(t1.keyword) 
    FROM 
    interests AS t1 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT 
            keyword,count(*) totalcount 
      FROM 
            interests GROUP BY keyword
      )t2 
ON t1.keyword=t2.keyword group by t1.keyword 
   ORDER BY t2.totalcount DESC
```

[Sql Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f937/15)